# php mail() не работает html

Tags: php

Использую функцию php - mail() для отправки сообщений на email

```
<?php
$title = 'Email'; 
$mess = 'hello';
$to = '*****@mail.ru'; //
$mailheaders = "Content-type: text/**plain**; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: \"no-reply@example.ru\" <no-reply@example.ru>\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: no-reply@example.ru\r\n";
$send = mail($to, $title, $mess, $mailheaders);
echo $send;
?>
```

Сообщение отсылаются и все хорошо

Но если изменить Content-type: text/plain на text/html

```
 <?php
$title = 'Email'; 
$mess = 'hello';
$to = '*****@mail.ru'; //
$mailheaders = "Content-type: text/**html**; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: \"no-reply@example.ru\" <no-reply@example.ru>\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: no-reply@example.ru\r\n";
$send = mail($to, $title, $mess, $mailheaders);
echo $send;
?>
```

Так уже сообщения не приходят, а нужно использовать html в письме.

Примечание - Использовал бесплатные хостинги.
Как выяснить в чем проблема, в хосте или я что-то не так делаю.
Использовал 2 бесплатных хостинга и результат одинаковый, с type/plain письма приходят с обоих хостов, с type/html ни с одного не приходят

Comment: А что если Content-type поставить в конец заголовков?

Comment: а что это изменит?

Comment: не помогло решение

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `PHPmailer` - он сам настроит нужные заголовки если указать

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

1. [Исчерпывающая инструкция по phpmailer](http://www.sesmikcms.ru/pages/read/ischerpyvajuschaja-instrukcija-po-php-mailer/)
2. [Код на github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)